# How to "compose" variable names in C++?

Tags: c++

Given an hypothetical situation like this:

```
int val1, val2, val3, choice;
while (expression) {
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1) {
        val1 += expression;
    } else if (choice == 2) {
        val2 += expression;
    } else if (choice == 3) {
        val3 += expression;
    } else {
        expressions..;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to treat the variable names like strings, to be able to "compose" them?
This could be useful for example in the above example or even better in a for loop, adding the counter value to the variable name so that at every cycle a different variable will be called.

With a such feature, my above example would become something like:

```
int val1, val2, val3, choice;
while (expression) {
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3) {
        ['val' + choice] += expression;
    } else {
        expressions..;
    }
}
```

I don't think I picked the best example to represent the benefits of a such feature, anyway I used to do this a lot with PHP and SQL, using for example the the value of a counter in a loop to pick each time a different item of an array and state it in the new SQL statement.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible in C++?
If something isn't clear just let me know.
Thank you :)

Comment: You explicitly mentioned array in your question. C++ has arrays like every other language.

Comment: You can use Arrays

Comment: Yes, I know. I mentioned it to make an other example for how a such feature could be used.

Comment: use `map` between string and value

Comment: If you know that arrays exist, why don't you just make `val` an array?

Comment: Yes now I see the point, making an array with all the variables...

Comment: Sorry, I have just started with C++ for a different environment and just haven't thought of it XD

Comment: I'm gonna read about `map` though

Comment: Try a dynamic array.

Answer (score 7):

Try an array:

```
int vals[3] = {0}, choice;
while (expression) {
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 3) {
        // arrays are indexed starting at 0
        vals[choice-1] += expression;
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The real solution is an array. But if you really want to attach a different name to your value, you can use a map:

```
std::map<std::string, int> vals;

while (expression) {
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3) {
        vals[std::string{"val"} + choice] += expression;
    } else {
        expressions..;
    }
}
```

The content of the map may look something like this:

```
"val1" -> 4
"val2" -> 3
"val3" -> 12
```

A map with strings in keys will be the closest thing you can have to dynamic names.

But I can assure you, the array solution is *better* in this specific case. Dynamic names are a bad idea and get used to static name if you want to c++.

Answer (score 1):

Variables names are compile time, not runtime objects.

It is very common to have an array when you need to identify objects by low integers.

```
int val[3]; // val1, val2, val3

// -1 because arrays are 0-based
val[choice-1];
```

You can use a hash table (called an unordered_map) to do the same thing with strings, as someone else has suggested. But unordered_maps are quite heavyweight objects. 
You can also use #defines and the ## token paste operator but not to paste a variable. Only compile time identifiers can be concatenated with ##.